# beginner stymied getting Ubuntu 18.10 Studio to open 7zip files or load 7zip archive program

Tags: software-center, 7zip

I need help setting up my new Pianoteq 6 Stage on my pc with a brand new Ubuntu Studio operating system. I think it is version Ubuntu 18.10.

I am stymied by the inability to get my new Ubuntu operating system to accept the file archiving program needed to  extract the Pianoteq program. Pianoteq comes in a “7zip”  archive, but, Ubuntu's package or archive manager does not recognize the 7zip file format. So, it won't extract the files or install Pianoteq.

This PC is not connected to the internet, and I have to travel to an intenet wifi hotspot to access the internet. So, I typically bring programs or files to it by shuttling files via "internet-my laptop- USB stick-PC" method.

So, I found the 7zip website, downloaded the 7zip program file onto the USB stick, got home with the 7zip program, put the USB stick into the PC and dragged the 7zip program file onto the computer's desktop. I double clicked it, and, Ubuntu looked like it was going to install it. A screen very similar to the ones used in my earlier Ubuntu's Software Center appeared, including the developer's description of the 7zip program, an install progress bar, and a button that said “Install” or something like that. When I clicked the Install button, nothing happened, other than the word “Pending” appearing near that progress bar.  But, the progress bar never moved in 30 minutes. Retries all produced the same result.

So, I am now stuck trying to get my Ubuntu to accept the 7zip archive program so I can then install my Pianoteq 6 program.

Has anyone here had the same problem getting their Linux or Ubuntu operating system to recognize and accept the 7zip program?

Or, does anyone here know how I can get 7zip into the Ubuntu computer through the “terminal” command lines?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

To install that program use these steps when you have an internet connection

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install p7zip-full
```

But to use them offline download the binary file with:

1. Make a directory

   ```
   mkdir ~/binary
   ```
2. Then change into that folder in step 1 above and download the binaries

   - `cd ~/binary`

     ```
     sudo apt-get download p7zip-full
     sudo apt-get download p7zip
     ```
3. Now install it with

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

Comment: Thanks, George. I will try that and report back here.